# How to Create Query like CSV without pivot?

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, pivot

i have a trouble when i want to create a csv From Table ..

here it's my table sample...

```
ID  HEADER_row  Value_row
1   A             100
2   B             200
3   C             300
4   D             400
5   E             500
6   A             600
7   B             700
8   C             800
9   D             900
10  E             1000
```

and its the csv data model that i want to create, check this out guys:

```
A   B   C   D   E   A   B   C   D   E
100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000
```

and

```
A   B   C   D   E
1OO 2OO 3OO 4OO 5OO
600 700 800 900 1000
```

I Already try this for my first model problem...

```
SELECT STUFF(
(SELECT ',' + s.ElementName
FROM tableName s
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') 

UNION ALL

SELECT STUFF(
(SELECT ',' + s.Value
FROM tableName s
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
```

but it give me the result like this:

```
A   B   C   D   E   A   B   C   D   E
100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000
```

now i want to get the other result like this

```
 A  B   C   D   E
    1OO 2OO 3OO 4OO 5OO
    600 700 800 900 1000
```

what kind of query i should use on my problem beside using pivot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split this data into separate rows you are going to include the use of `row_number()` in the second query that gets the `Value_row`:

By applying the `row_number()` you can partition the data by the `Header_row` value to assign two separate number:

```
select Value_row,
  row_number() over(partition by header_row order by id) rn
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a018f/1). This query gives the result:

```
| VALUE_ROW | RN |
------------------
|       100 |  1 |
|       600 |  2 |
|       200 |  1 |
|       700 |  2 |
|       300 |  1 |
|       800 |  2 |
|       400 |  1 |
|       900 |  2 |
|       500 |  1 |
|      1000 |  2 |
```

Then you incorporate this into your existing query so the code will be:

```
SELECT STUFF(
            (SELECT ',' + s.HEADER_row
            FROM yourtable s
            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') 
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 
  STUFF(
            (SELECT ',' + cast(Value_row as varchar(50))
            from
            (
              select Value_row,
                row_number() over(partition by header_row order by id) rn
              from yourtable
            ) src      
            where r.rn = src.rn
            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM
(
  select Value_row,
    row_number() over(partition by header_row order by id) rn
  from yourtable
)r ;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a018f/4)

This gives the result:

```
|                 LIST |
------------------------
|  A,B,C,D,E,A,B,C,D,E |
|  100,200,300,400,500 |
| 600,700,800,900,1000 |
```